# CSS: dashed border under 2 divs

Tags: html, css

[image: Sample image]

Please see the attached image and fiddle. The idea is to have 2 tables side by side (the blue boxes) and you can select a row in each table and then press the red link button below. The lines that connect the boxes and link buttons need to be a dashed border. The height of the blue boxes will vary.

[Here you can find the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfeaj3f7/6/) of what I have so far.

```
<div class="container cf">
    <div class="link">
        <div class="linkButton">
            <input type="button" value="link" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab table1">Table left </div>
    <div class="tab table2">Table right</div>
</div>
```

I am having difficulties centering the link button and am also wondering about how robust my HTML is because of positioning the link button and container using negative values.

Any suggestions on a better structure are welcome. I need to support IE7 so I cannot take advantage of :before, :after and other pseudo elements.

Comment: `am also wondering about how robust my HTML is` Robust ? :/ You are mixing relative and absolute positioning with floating elements with pseudo elements... the whole thing could probably be done a lot easily

Comment: Also if the button is something like "copy the row from table 1 to table 2" or similar, consider using Drag and Drop for a better user experience

Comment: *I cannot take advantage of :before, :after and other pseudo elements* - yet in your fiddle, you're using them? Then as @AndreaLigios has already said, floating and positing elements? I doubt this would be robust in current browsers, let alone IE7.

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the HTML, i know it's not robust in it's current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplified version of it, I changed the order of the tables, so the floating one first, therefore clear fix won't be necessary.

```
<div class="tab table2">Table right</div>
<div class="tab table1">Table left</div>
```

Full code/demo below.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.tab {
    background: #00395c;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px; /*try a different height*/
}
.table2 {
    float: right;
}
.link {
    border: 2px dashed grey;
    border-top-width: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -50px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
.link input {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="link">
        <input type="button" value="link" />
    </div>
    <div class="tab table2">Table right</div>
    <div class="tab table1">Table left</div>
</div>
<div class="anotherDiv">This is another div</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x79c28gz/)**

Comment: Thanks, seems to work well. Should i add the clearfix back in if i need the .table1 element to appear before .table2 ?

Comment: @grimmus Yes, and according to [the author](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) the cf hack works fine on IE6+.

Answer (score 0):

To center the button change `absolute` position for the `relative`:

```
.link input[type="button"] {position:relative; top:50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xfeaj3f7/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you change css to following it should help you:

```
.link input[type="button"] {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xfeaj3f7/8/